# Cannot remove unwanted overloads

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic

The function `transform` conducted by

```
const std::vector<int>         a = {1,     2,       3,       4,    5};
const std::vector<double>      b = {1.2,   4.5,     0.6};
const std::vector<std::string> c = {"hi", "howdy", "hello", "bye"};
std::vector<double> result(5);

transform<Foo> (result.begin(),
    a.begin(), a.end(),
    b.begin(), b.end(),
    c.begin(), c.end());
```

is to carry out a generalization of `std::transform` on multiple containers, outputing the results in the vector `result`.  One function with signature `(int, double, const std::string&)` would apparently be needed to handle the three containers in this example.  But because the containers have different lengths, we instead need to use some overloads.  I will test this using these member overloads of a holder class Foo:

```
static int execute (int i, double d, const std::string& s) {return i + d + s.length();}
static int execute (int i, const std::string& s) {return 2 * i + s.length();}
static int execute (int i) {return 3 * i - 1;}
```

However, the program will not compile unless I define three other overloads that are never even called, namely with arguments `(int, double)`, `(const std::string&)` and `()`.  I want to remove these overloads, but the program won't let me.  You can imagine the problem this would cause if we had more than 3 containers (of different lengths), forcing overloads with many permutations of arguments to be defined when they are not even being used.

Here is my working program that will apparently show why these extraneous overloads are needed.  I don't see how or why the are forced to be defined, and want to remove them.  Why must they be there, and how to remove the need for them?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

bool allTrue (bool a) {return a;}

template <typename... B>
bool allTrue (bool a, B... b) {return a && allTrue(b...);}

template <typename F, size_t... Js, typename Tuple>
typename F::return_type screenArguments (std::index_sequence<>, std::index_sequence<Js...>, Tuple& tuple) {
    return F::execute (*std::get<Js>(tuple)++...);
}

// Thanks to Barry for coming up with screenArguments.
template <typename F, std::size_t I, size_t... Is, size_t... Js, typename Tuple>
typename F::return_type screenArguments (std::index_sequence<I, Is...>, std::index_sequence<Js...>, Tuple& tuple) {
    if (std::get<2*I>(tuple) != std::get<2*I+1>(tuple))
        return screenArguments<F> (std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, std::index_sequence<Js..., 2*I>{}, tuple);
    else
        return screenArguments<F> (std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, std::index_sequence<Js...>{}, tuple);
}

template <typename F, typename Tuple>
typename F::return_type passCertainArguments (Tuple& tuple) {
    return screenArguments<F> (std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value / 2>{},
        std::index_sequence<>{}, tuple);
}

template <typename F, typename OutputIterator, std::size_t... Is, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transformHelper (OutputIterator result, const std::index_sequence<Is...>&, InputIterators... iterators) {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(iterators...);
    while (!allTrue(std::get<2*Is>(tuple) == std::get<2*Is + 1>(tuple)...))
        *result++ = passCertainArguments<F>(tuple);
    return result;
}

template <typename F, typename OutputIterator, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transform (OutputIterator result, InputIterators... iterators) {
    return transformHelper<F> (result, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InputIterators) / 2>{}, iterators...);
}

// Testing
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    using return_type = int;
    static int execute (int i, double d, const std::string& s) {return i + d + s.length();}
    static int execute (int i, const std::string& s) {return 2 * i + s.length();}
    static int execute (int i) {return 3 * i - 1;}
    // These overloads are never called, but apparently must still be defined.  
    static int execute () {std::cout << "Oveload4 called.\n";  return 0;}
    static int execute (int i, double d) {std::cout << "Oveload5 called.\n";  return i + d;}
    static int execute (const std::string& s) {std::cout << "Oveload6 called.\n";  return s.length();}
};

int main() {
    const std::vector<int>         a = {1,     2,       3,       4,    5};
    const std::vector<double>      b = {1.2,   4.5,     0.6};
    const std::vector<std::string> c = {"hi", "howdy", "hello", "bye"};
    std::vector<double> result(5);

    transform<Foo> (result.begin(),
        a.begin(), a.end(),
        b.begin(), b.end(),
        c.begin(), c.end());
    for (double x : result) std::cout << x << ' ';  std::cout << '\n';
    // 4 11 8 11 14 (correct output)
}
```

Comment: Don't go messing with templates. What will you do if two containers have the same types?

Comment: Because those overloads would be needed if, say, the sequence of strings are longer than the other two. Since the length of sequences is a run-time property, you can't know whether they are needed at compile time. (The only reason the compiler is not demanding the full set of combinations is because `double` is implicitly convertible to `int`.)

Comment: I suspected something like that.  So what is the proper design to avoid this problem?  If such a solution is too monumental an undertaking, can you at least suggest another method?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this in the first place? The whole omitting arguments thing seems fragile and suspect.

Comment: Sorry, just practising some programming with templates.  Feel free to ignore this problem unless you find it interesting enough to solve it (properly).  So you are suggesting forget about using overloads, and try something like multiple lambdas all with the same signature `(int, double, const std::string&)` and then at run-time call the appropriate lambda based on which arguments are missing?  I thought of that first, but quickly abandoned the idea.

Comment: @ T.C   I found a new solution and welcome your sense of any problems (other than being unsimplified, as it is only my first working draft).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not know at compile time which combinations of functions will be used in runtime. So you have to implement all the `2^N` functions for every combination. Also your approach will not work when you have containers with the same types.

If you want to stick with templates, my idea is to implement the function something like this:

```
template <bool Arg1, bool Arg2, bool Arg3>
static int execute (int *i, double *d, const std::string *s);
```

The template arguments `Arg1, Arg2, Arg3` represent the validity of each parameter. The compiler will automatically generate all the `2^N` implementations for every parameter combination. Feel free to use `if` statements inside this function instead of template specialization - they will be resolved at compile time to `if (true)` or `if (false)`.

Comment: I found a new solution, and welcome your critiques.  Including stating cases where it will break down.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got!  Template the function `Foo::execute` according to the number of arguments that are actually needed, and let them all have the same arguments:

```
struct Foo {
    using return_type = int;
    template <std::size_t> static return_type execute (int, double, const std::string&);
};

template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<3> (int i, double d, const std::string& s) {return i + d + s.length();}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<2> (int i, double, const std::string& s) {return 2 * i + s.length();}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<1> (int i, double, const std::string&) {return 3 * i - 1;}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<0> (int, double, const std::string&) {return 0;}  // The only redundant specialization that needs to be defined.
```

Here is the full solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <iterator>

bool allTrue (bool b) {return b;}

template <typename... Bs>
bool allTrue (bool b, Bs... bs) {return b && allTrue(bs...);}

template <typename F, std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
typename F::return_type countArgumentsNeededAndExecute (Tuple&, const std::index_sequence<>&, Args&&... args) {
    return F::template execute<N>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename F, std::size_t N, typename Tuple, std::size_t I, size_t... Is, typename... Args>
typename F::return_type countArgumentsNeededAndExecute (Tuple& tuple, const std::index_sequence<I, Is...>&, Args&&... args) {  // Pass tuple by reference, because its iterator elements will be modified (by being incremented).
    return (std::get<2*I>(tuple) != std::get<2*I + 1>(tuple)) ?
        countArgumentsNeededAndExecute<F, N+1> (tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...,  // The number of arguments to be used increases by 1.
            *std::get<2*I>(tuple)++) :  // Pass the value that will be used and increment the iterator.
        countArgumentsNeededAndExecute<F, N> (tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...,
            typename std::iterator_traits<typename std::tuple_element<2*I, Tuple>::type>::value_type{});  // Pass the default value (it will be ignored anyway), and don't increment the iterator.  Hence, the number of arguments to be used does not change.
}

template <typename F, typename OutputIterator, std::size_t... Is, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transformHelper (OutputIterator result, const std::index_sequence<Is...>& indices, InputIterators... iterators) {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(iterators...);  // Cannot be const, as the iterators are being incremented.
    while (!allTrue(std::get<2*Is>(tuple) == std::get<2*Is + 1>(tuple)...))
        *result++ = countArgumentsNeededAndExecute<F, 0> (tuple, indices);  // Start the count at 0.  Examine 'indices', causing the count to increase one by one.
    return result;
}

template <typename F, typename OutputIterator, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transform (OutputIterator result, InputIterators... iterators) {
    return transformHelper<F> (result, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InputIterators) / 2>{}, iterators...);
}

// Testing
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    using return_type = int;
    template <std::size_t> static return_type execute (int, double, const std::string&);
};

// Template the function Foo::execute according to the number of arguments that are actually needed:
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<3> (int i, double d, const std::string& s) {return i + d + s.length();}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<2> (int i, double, const std::string& s) {return 2 * i + s.length();}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<1> (int i, double, const std::string&) {return 3 * i - 1;}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<0> (int, double, const std::string&) {return 0;}  // The only redundant specialization that needs to be defined.

int main() {
    const std::vector<int>         a = {1,     2,       3,       4,    5};
    const std::vector<double>      b = {1.2,   4.5,     0.6};
    const std::vector<std::string> c = {"hi", "howdy", "hello", "bye"};
    std::vector<double> result(5);

    transform<Foo> (result.begin(),
        a.begin(), a.end(),
        b.begin(), b.end(),
        c.begin(), c.end());
    for (double x : result) std::cout << x << ' ';  std::cout << '\n';
    // 4 11 8 11 14 (correct output)
}
```

And a second solution using Andrey Nasonov's bool templates to generate all 2^N overloads needed.  Note that the above solution requires only N+1 template instantations for the overloads though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

bool allTrue (bool b) {return b;}

template <typename... Bs>
bool allTrue (bool b, Bs... bs) {return b && allTrue(bs...);}

template <bool...> struct BoolPack {};

template <typename F, typename Tuple, bool... Bs, typename... Args>
typename F::return_type checkArgumentsAndExecute (const Tuple&, const std::index_sequence<>&, BoolPack<Bs...>, Args&&... args) {
    return F::template execute<Bs...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename F, typename Tuple, std::size_t I, size_t... Is, bool... Bs, typename... Args>
typename F::return_type checkArgumentsAndExecute (Tuple& tuple, const std::index_sequence<I, Is...>&, BoolPack<Bs...>, Args&&... args) {  // Pass tuple by reference, because its iterators elements will be modified (by being incremented).
    return (std::get<2*I>(tuple) != std::get<2*I+1>(tuple)) ?
        checkArgumentsAndExecute<F> (tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, BoolPack<Bs..., true>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...,
            *std::get<2*I>(tuple)++) :  // Pass the value that will be used and increment the iterator.
        checkArgumentsAndExecute<F> (tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>{}, BoolPack<Bs..., false>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...,
            typename std::iterator_traits<typename std::tuple_element<2*I, Tuple>::type>::value_type{});  // Pass the default value (it will be ignored anyway), and don't increment the iterator.
}

template <typename F, typename OutputIterator, std::size_t... Is, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transformHelper (OutputIterator& result, const std::index_sequence<Is...>& indices, InputIterators... iterators) {
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(iterators...);  // Cannot be const, as the iterators are being incremented.
    while (!allTrue(std::get<2*Is>(tuple) == std::get<2*Is + 1>(tuple)...))
        *result++ = checkArgumentsAndExecute<F> (tuple, indices, BoolPack<>{});
    return result;
}

template <typename F, typename OutputIterator, typename... InputIterators>
OutputIterator transform (OutputIterator result, InputIterators... iterators) {
    return transformHelper<F> (result, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(InputIterators) / 2>{}, iterators...);
}

// Testing
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    using return_type = int;
    template <bool B1, bool B2, bool B3> static return_type execute (int, double, const std::string&) {return 0;}  // All necessary overloads defined at once here.
};

// Specializations of Foo::execute<B1,B2,B3>(int, double, const std::string&) that will actually be called by transform<Foo> (it is the client's responsibility to define these overloads based on the containers passed to transform<Foo>).
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<true, true, true> (int i, double d, const std::string& s) {return i + d + s.length();}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<true, false, true> (int i, double, const std::string& s) {return 2 * i + s.length();}
template <> Foo::return_type Foo::execute<true, false, false> (int i, double, const std::string&) {return 3 * i - 1;}

int main() {
    const std::vector<int>         a = {1,     2,       3,       4,    5};
    const std::vector<double>      b = {1.2,   4.5,     0.6};
    const std::vector<std::string> c = {"hi", "howdy", "hello", "bye"};
    std::vector<double> result(5);

    transform<Foo> (result.begin(),
        a.begin(), a.end(),
        b.begin(), b.end(),
        c.begin(), c.end());
    for (double x : result) std::cout << x << ' ';  std::cout << '\n';
    // 4 11 8 11 14 (correct output)
}
```

Comment: What will you do when passing the default value is not possible? The perfect solution would be also allowing variable numbers of arguments passed to `execute` by skipping default arguments.

Comment: @  Andrey Nasonov   That's a good point.  I assumed the default constructor is always valid.  My implementation of your method (written above) also makes that assumption.  But something needs to be passed into the arguments that are not being used.  So you are suggesting to turn every argument to pointers and pass `nullptr` by default?

Comment: My idea is based on your one: https://ideone.com/Cp22ia - but the  problem here is passing `std::string` as an argument instead of `const std::string &`.

Comment: Using `const int&`, `const double&`, `const std::string&` and `const Args&...` solves that new problem (tested).  So now apparently the solution is flawless, except the forcing of 2^N template instantiations instead of ideally just N (as in my second solution, but which had the more serious drawback of forcing default constructor calls that may not exist).